# How is it possible that a 4.5gb DVD claims 415gb of contents?

Tags: software-rec, dvd, dvd-burning

I am copying a 4.7 GB dvd contents into my local drive but the total size of DVD is being shown as 415 GB!. How is that possible? Because of which it is showing less space (as my drive is of 150 GB) and thus cannot be copied?

I am surprised that how a 4.7 GB dvd contains 415 GB data? Its a movie DVD (contains dual subtitles and dual language, if that helps)

Attached is the image for reference

[image]

Inside the DVD the video folder shows 415 GB

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account its probably not magical compression... there's a bunch of dummy files there to make the directory look bigger. Rather cute trick really. I'd probably suspect there's a load of files that won't open in there, and one real one.

Wikipedia mentions this is possible, but there's [no real details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc_and_DVD_copy_protection#Filesystems_.2F_Dummy_files)

Comment: Ok.. so you mean that there are dummy files that make directory look bigger..?? but that i am not able to copy into my local PC

Comment: yup. Takes advantage of the vagaries of the file system. I wouldn't be surprised if there's other copy protection as well. In general, one dosen't 'simply' copy files off a DVD and expect it to work - you would need to use a dvd ripper of some sort for backups, assuming thats what you want to do

Comment: Yes.. i cant copy the DVD as well.. Its protected.. Which DVD ripper i need to use?? How can one copy-protect the DVD?

Comment: eh, that's a whole different question, and one that's well covered on the site. handbrake is a good bet however. Copy protection usually tends to involve either encryption, or breaking the standards of the media.